# How to Filter multi-select values in nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

Please find the demo link.  https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-dubinsky-t0hcn?file=/src/nestead-table/index.js

I am not able to filter multi-valued selected items in JSON data.

This is the data we are passing.

```
   const jsonData = [
  {
    isMaster: false,
    selected: false,
    ID: 0,
    "Profile Type": "Line of Business",
    Risk: [
      {
        isMaster: false,
        selected: false,
        ID: 0.1,
        "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating": "Not Assessed",
        Control: [
          {
            isMaster: false,
            selected: false,
            ID: 0.2,
            "Control Classification": "key",
            "Control Effectiveness Rating": "Partially Effective"
          },
          {
            isMaster: false,
            selected: false,
            ID: 0.21,
            "Control Classification": "Compensating",
            "Control Effectiveness Rating": "Partially Effective"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        isMaster: false,
        selected: false,
        ID: 0.11,
        "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating":
          "Insignificant",
          Control: [
            {
              isMaster: false,
              selected: false,
              ID: 0.12,
              "Control Classification": "Arrangement",
              "Control Effectiveness Rating": "Partially Effective"
            },
            {
              isMaster: false,
              selected: false,
              ID: 0.13,
              "Control Classification": "Compensating",
              "Control Effectiveness Rating": "Effective"
            }
          ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    isMaster: false,
    selected: false,
    ID: 1,
    "Profile Type": "Business Unit (BU) / Support Unit (SU)",
    Risk: [
      {
        isMaster: false,
        selected: false,
        ID: 1.1,
        "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating": "Low",
        Control: [
          {
            isMaster: false,
            selected: false,
            ID: 1.2,
            "Control Classification": "key",
            "Control Effectiveness Rating": "Partially Effective"
          },
          {
            isMaster: false,
            selected: false,
            ID: 1.21,
            "Control Classification": "Arrangement",
            "Control Effectiveness Rating": "Partially Effective"
          },
          {
            isMaster: false,
            selected: false,
            ID: 1.22,
            "Control Classification": "key",
            "Control Effectiveness Rating": "Effective"
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        isMaster: false,
        selected: false,
        ID: 1.11,
        "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating":
          "Medium",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    isMaster: false,
    selected: false,
    ID: 2,
    Name: "0940375C025200FAA38ED98A F9DE03D61ADAB727BA8C26D4",
    "Business Profile Owner": "Susheel",
    Folder: "CBA / Audit",
    "Profile Type": "Business Profile Instances",
    Risk: [
      {
        isMaster: false,
        selected: false,
        ID: 2.1,
        "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating": "High",
        Control: [
          {
            isMaster: false,
            selected: false,
            ID: 2.2,
            "Control Classification": "Arrangement",
            "Control Effectiveness Rating": "Not Determined"
          },
          {
            isMaster: false,
            selected: false,
            ID: 2.21,
            "Control Classification": "Arrangement",
            "Control Effectiveness Rating": "Not Tested"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        isMaster: false,
        selected: false,
        ID: 2.11,
        "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating":
          "very High",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    isMaster: false,
    selected: false,
    ID: 3,
    "Profile Type": "Supplier",
    Risk: [
      {
        isMaster: false,
        selected: false,
        ID: 3.1,
        "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating":
          "Lindgren",
        Control: [
          {
            isMaster: false,
            selected: false,
            ID: 3.2,
            "Control Classification": "Arrangement",
            "Control Effectiveness Rating": "Not Tested"
          },
          {
            isMaster: false,
            selected: false,
            ID: 3.21,
            "Control Classification": "Arrangement",
            "Control Effectiveness Rating": "Not Tested"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        isMaster: false,
        selected: false,
        ID: 3.11,
        "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating":
          "Lindgren",
      }
    ]
  },
];
```

on selecting multi-select input we will be getting the following data.

```
const selection1 =  [{name: "Business Unit (BU) / Support Unit (SU)", type: "bp", column: "Profile Type"}];
```

if section1 is selected then the following will be the output.

```
[{
  isMaster: false,
  selected: false,
  ID: 1,
  "Profile Type": "Business Unit (BU) / Support Unit (SU)",
  Risk: [
    {
      isMaster: false,
      selected: false,
      ID: 1.1,
      "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating": "Low",
      Control: [
        {
          isMaster: false,
          selected: false,
          ID: 1.2,
          "Control Classification": "key",
          "Control Effectiveness Rating": "Partially Effective"
        },
        {
          isMaster: false,
          selected: false,
          ID: 1.21,
          "Control Classification": "Arrangement",
          "Control Effectiveness Rating": "Partially Effective"
        },
        {
          isMaster: false,
          selected: false,
          ID: 1.22,
          "Control Classification": "key",
          "Control Effectiveness Rating": "Effective"
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      isMaster: false,
      selected: false,
      ID: 1.11,
      "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating":
        "Medium",
    }
  ]
}]
```

.

```
const selection2 =  [{name: "Low", type: "Risk", column: "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating"},{name: "0.11", type: "Risk", column: "id"}];
```

.

if selection2 is selected then the following will be the output.

```
[ ] // since no matching values.
```

.

```
const selection3 = [ {name: "Partially Effective", type: "Control", column: "Control Effectiveness Rating"},{name: "key", type: "Control", column: "Control Classification"} ]
```

if selection3 is selected then the following will be the output.

```
[{
    isMaster: false,
    selected: false,
    ID: 0,
    "Profile Type": "Line of Business",
    Risk: [
      {
        isMaster: false,
        selected: false,
        ID: 0.1,
        "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating": "Not Assessed",
        Control: [
          {
            isMaster: false,
            selected: false,
            ID: 0.2,
            "Control Classification": "key",
            "Control Effectiveness Rating": "Partially Effective"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    isMaster: false,
    selected: false,
    ID: 1,
    "Profile Type": "Business Unit (BU) / Support Unit (SU)",
    Risk: [
      {
        isMaster: false,
        selected: false,
        ID: 1.1,
        "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating": "Low",
        Control: [
          {
            isMaster: false,
            selected: false,
            ID: 1.2,
            "Control Classification": "key",
            "Control Effectiveness Rating": "Partially Effective"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }]
```

.

```
const selection4 = [ {name: "Low", type: "Risk", column: "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating"},{name: "key", type: "Control", column: "Control Classification"} ]
```

if selection4 is selected then the following will be the output.

```
[{
  isMaster: false,
  selected: false,
  ID: 1,
  "Profile Type": "Business Unit (BU) / Support Unit (SU)",
  Risk: [
    {
      isMaster: false,
      selected: false,
      ID: 1.1,
      "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating": "Low",
      Control: [
        {
          isMaster: false,
          selected: false,
          ID: 1.2,
          "Control Classification": "key",
          "Control Effectiveness Rating": "Partially Effective"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}]
```

.

```
const selection5 =  [{name: "Business Unit (BU) / Support Unit (SU)", type: "bp", column: "Profile Type"},
    {name: "Low", type: "Risk", column: "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating"},
    {name: "key", type: "Control", column: "Control Classification"},
    {name: "Partially Effective", type: "Control", column: "Control Effectiveness Rating"}];
```

if selection5 is used then we should display all the object which matches the particular name from selection1 and the column is "Profile Type".

All the above sections will be dynamic. if the **type** is **control** or **risk** in the above sections they are sub Arrays of each object and if **type='bp'** then it's the main object with ID's 0,1,2,3

if selection5 is used then the following will be the output of it.

```
{
  isMaster: false,
  selected: false,
  ID: 1,
  "Profile Type": "Business Unit (BU) / Support Unit (SU)",
  Risk: [
    {
      isMaster: false,
      selected: false,
      ID: 1.1,
      "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating": "Low",
      Control: [
        {
          isMaster: false,
          selected: false,
          ID: 1.2,
          "Control Classification": "key",
          "Control Effectiveness Rating": "Partially Effective"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

.

```
const selection6 = [ {name: "Low", type: "Risk", column: "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating"},{name: "Not Assessed", type: "Risk", column: "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating"} ];
```

if selection6  is selected then the following will be the output.
(if it has the same column then we need to use **||** operation)
(if it has different columns then we need to use **&&** operation)
(if it has the same and different columns then we need to use **OR & AND** operation respectively)

```
[
  {
  isMaster: false,
  selected: false,
  ID: 0,
  "Profile Type": "Line of Business",
  Risk: [
    {
      isMaster: false,
      selected: false,
      ID: 0.1,
      "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating": "Not Assessed",
      Control: [
        {
          isMaster: false,
          selected: false,
          ID: 0.2,
          "Control Classification": "key",
          "Control Effectiveness Rating": "Partially Effective"
        },
        {
          isMaster: false,
          selected: false,
          ID: 0.21,
          "Control Classification": "Compensating",
          "Control Effectiveness Rating": "Partially Effective"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},{
  isMaster: false,
  selected: false,
  ID: 1,
  "Profile Type": "Business Unit (BU) / Support Unit (SU)",
  Risk: [
    {
      isMaster: false,
      selected: false,
      ID: 1.1,
      "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating": "Low",
      Control: [
        {
          isMaster: false,
          selected: false,
          ID: 1.2,
          "Control Classification": "key",
          "Control Effectiveness Rating": "Partially Effective"
        },
        {
          isMaster: false,
          selected: false,
          ID: 1.21,
          "Control Classification": "Arrangement",
          "Control Effectiveness Rating": "Partially Effective"
        },
        {
          isMaster: false,
          selected: false,
          ID: 1.22,
          "Control Classification": "key",
          "Control Effectiveness Rating": "Effective"
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}]
```

.

```
const selection7 = [ {name: "key", type: "Control", column: "Control Classification"},{name: "Compensating", type: "Control", column: "Control Classification"} ]
```

if selection7  is selected then the following will be the output.

```
[  {
  isMaster: false,
  selected: false,
  ID: 0,
  "Profile Type": "Line of Business",
  Risk: [
    {
      isMaster: false,
      selected: false,
      ID: 0.1,
      "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating": "Not Assessed",
      Control: [
        {
          isMaster: false,
          selected: false,
          ID: 0.2,
          "Control Classification": "key",
          "Control Effectiveness Rating": "Partially Effective"
        },
        {
          isMaster: false,
          selected: false,
          ID: 0.21,
          "Control Classification": "Compensating",
          "Control Effectiveness Rating": "Partially Effective"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      isMaster: false,
      selected: false,
      ID: 0.11,
      "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating":
        "Insignificant",
        Control: [
          {
            isMaster: false,
            selected: false,
            ID: 0.13,
            "Control Classification": "Compensating",
            "Control Effectiveness Rating": "Effective"
          }
        ]
    }
  ]
},
{
  isMaster: false,
  selected: false,
  ID: 1,
  "Profile Type": "Business Unit (BU) / Support Unit (SU)",
  Risk: [
    {
      isMaster: false,
      selected: false,
      ID: 1.1,
      "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating": "Low",
      Control: [
        {
          isMaster: false,
          selected: false,
          ID: 1.2,
          "Control Classification": "key",
          "Control Effectiveness Rating": "Partially Effective"
        },
        {
          isMaster: false,
          selected: false,
          ID: 1.22,
          "Control Classification": "key",
          "Control Effectiveness Rating": "Effective"
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}
]
```

.

```
const selection8 = [{name: "Low",
type: "Risk",
column: "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating",
},{ 
name: "Lindgren",
type: "Risk",
column: "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating",
},{
name: "High",
type: "Risk",
column: "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating",
},
{
name: "Very High",
type: "Risk",
column: "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating",
},{
name: "Partially Effective",
type: "Control",
column: "Control Effectiveness Rating",
},{
name: "Effective",
type: "Control",
column: "Control Effectiveness Rating",
},{
name: "Not Determined",
type: "Control",
column: "Control Effectiveness Rating",
},{
name: "Not Assessed",
type: "Risk",
column: "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating",
}
]
```

Comment: You have to tell us what is your problem

Comment: @RogerPeixoto I am not able to filter multi-valued selected items in JSON data.

Comment: please add the wanted result of `selection2`.

Comment: @NinaScholz  added it.

Comment: why not `ID: 1.22,` in the result for selection2?

Comment: @NinaScholz **ID: 1.22** is not considered because if you see the **section2** it has 2 values of **type=control**  we need to add **&&** operation for it. both column's names should match.... not one.

Comment: @NinaScholz FYR  **type='bp'**  in selection2 then it's the main object with ID's 0,1,2,3

Comment: @NinaScholz it's falling when selection is of this type.

      const selection = **[
         {
            name: "Medium",
            type: "Risk",
            column: "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating"
        }
    ]**

this will be the output of it.
{
  isMaster: false,
  selected: false,
  ID: 1,
  "Profile Type": "Business Unit (BU) / Support Unit (SU)",
  Risk: [
    {
      isMaster: false,
      selected: false,
      ID: 1.11,
      "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating":
        "Medium",
    }
  ]
}

Comment: @NinaScholz can you help me please i am stuck on this. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: what does not work? what about my answer below?

Comment: @NinaScholz when the selection has  `[ { name: "Medium", type: "Risk", column: "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating" } ]` currently it's returning **all the data**

it should only return only matching object.

`{ isMaster: false, selected: false, ID: 1, "Profile Type": "Business Unit (BU) / Support Unit (SU)", Risk: [ { isMaster: false, selected: false, ID: 1.11, "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating": "Medium", } ] }`

Comment: @NinaScholz I have updated the type of selections in the above question it's dynamic
`selecion1 has an only type of bp **type=bp**`
`selecion2 has 2 types of risk **type=risk**`
`selecion3 has 2 types of control **type=control**`
`selecion4 has 2 types of **type=risk** and **type =control**`

Comment: the problem of the last request is not having a parent/root search. fo you have more missing middle/starting filtering parts?

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes in some cases there will be no parent filter only middle filtering will be there.
in that case, we can return along with the middle filter data and the parent obj.

Comment: @NinaScholz did you get any solution?

Comment: please add the wanted results of selection 1 to 5. btw, why not take the same property names for the selections, like `'risk'` vs `'Risk'`?

Comment: @NinaScholz Thank you so much for the answer...

 I see it's almost done but in some cases, it's not working.... selection6 and selection7 have the same **column**, in that case, it should use **OR** operation. if it's having a different column then we can use **AND** operation.

and for **selection8** the logic is crashing 
`FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0xb03020 node::Abort() [node]`

Please help me with this. Thank you so much.

Comment: @NinaScholz and also selection3 is not matching the wanted results.

Comment: `selection7` has wrong risk, should be control. and here it comes again `'key'` vs `Key`. it should be consitent over all data.

Comment: @NinaScholz Thanks for poiniting it out will update it.

Comment: @NinaScholz Thank you so much for the help :)

Comment: @NinaScholz Thanks for the Answer **it works** when the data is in the following format.
`[{
"Profile Type": "Line of Business",
Risk: [{
    isRisk: true, 
     Control: [{
     isControl:true
     }]
   }]
}]`

How to make your logic work to include an Obligation array as well.

`[{
"Profile Type": "Line of Business",
Risk: [{
    isRisk: true, 
     Control: [{
     isControl:true
     }]
   }],
Obligation: [{
    isObligation: true, 
     Control: [{
     isControl:true
     }]
   }],
}]`
I have tried this types = ['bp', 'Risk', 'Obligation', 'Control'] no luck

Comment: does it work this way? what goes wrong?

Comment: @NinaScholz I have created a separate post since we can't use the same logic please do the needful [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71455663/how-to-use-custom-filter-of-multi-select-values-in-nested-array-of-objects rest of the filter we need to keep as it is... We are adding Obligation Type inside **BP**. here **Obligation** plays a similar role as that of **Risk**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach generates an array of wanted selection and takes for left levels an objet with the name and an `all` property of `true` and adds this level only if the nesting parts returns some results.

**Values need to have the same notation in filter as in data!**

```js
const
    data = [{ isMaster: false, selected: false, ID: 0, "Profile Type": "Line of Business", Risk: [{ isMaster: false, selected: false, ID: 0.1, "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating": "Not Assessed", Control: [{ isMaster: false, selected: false, ID: 0.2, "Control Classification": "Key", "Control Effectiveness Rating": "Partially Effective" }, { isMaster: false, selected: false, ID: 0.21, "Control Classification": "Compensating", "Control Effectiveness Rating": "Partially Effective" }] }, { isMaster: false, selected: false, ID: 0.11, "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating": "Insignificant", Control: [{ isMaster: false, selected: false, ID: 0.12, "Control Classification": "Arrangement", "Control Effectiveness Rating": "Partially Effective" }, { isMaster: false, selected: false, ID: 0.13, "Control Classification": "Compensating", "Control Effectiveness Rating": "Effective" }] }] }, { isMaster: false, selected: false, ID: 1, "Profile Type": "Business Unit (BU) / Support Unit (SU)", Risk: [{ isMaster: false, selected: false, ID: 1.1, "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating": "Low", Control: [{ isMaster: false, selected: false, ID: 1.2, "Control Classification": "key", "Control Effectiveness Rating": "Partially Effective" }, { isMaster: false, selected: false, ID: 1.21, "Control Classification": "Arrangement", "Control Effectiveness Rating": "Partially Effective" }, { isMaster: false, selected: false, ID: 1.22, "Control Classification": "key", "Control Effectiveness Rating": "Effective" }] }, { isMaster: false, selected: false, ID: 1.11, "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating": "Medium" }] }, { isMaster: false, selected: false, ID: 2, Name: "0940375C025200FAA38ED98A F9DE03D61ADAB727BA8C26D4", "Business Profile Owner": "Susheel", Folder: "CBA / Audit", "Profile Type": "Business Profile Instances", Risk: [{ isMaster: false, selected: false, ID: 2.1, "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating": "High", Control: [{ isMaster: false, selected: false, ID: 2.2, "Control Classification": "Arrangement", "Control Effectiveness Rating": "Not Determined" }, { isMaster: false, selected: false, ID: 2.21, "Control Classification": "Arrangement", "Control Effectiveness Rating": "Not Tested" }] }, { isMaster: false, selected: false, ID: 2.11, "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating": "very High" }] }, { isMaster: false, selected: false, ID: 3, "Profile Type": "Supplier", Risk: [{ isMaster: false, selected: false, ID: 3.1, "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating": "Lindgren", Control: [{ isMaster: false, selected: false, ID: 3.2, "Control Classification": "Arrangement", "Control Effectiveness Rating": "Not Tested" }, { isMaster: false, selected: false, ID: 3.21, "Control Classification": "Arrangement", "Control Effectiveness Rating": "Not Tested" }] }, { isMaster: false, selected: false, ID: 3.11, "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating": "Lindgren" }] }],
    selection1 = [{ name: "Business Unit (BU) / Support Unit (SU)", type: "bp", column: "Profile Type" }],
    selection2 = [{ name: "Low", type: "Risk", column: "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating" }, { name: "0.11", type: "Risk", column: "id" }],
    selection3 = [{ name: "Partially Effective", type: "Control", column: "Control Effectiveness Rating" }, { name: "Key", type: "Control", column: "Control Classification" }],
    selection4 = [{ name: "Low", type: "Risk", column: "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating" }, { name: "Key", type: "Control", column: "Control Classification" }],
    selection5 = [{ name: "Business Unit (BU) / Support Unit (SU)", type: "bp", column: "Profile Type" }, { name: "Low", type: "Risk", column: "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating" }, { name: "key", type: "Control", column: "Control Classification" }, { name: "Partially Effective", type: "Control", column: "Control Effectiveness Rating" }],
    selection6 = [{ name: "Low", type: "Risk", column: "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating" }, { name: "Not Assessed", type: "Risk", column: "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating" }],
    selection7 = [{ name: "Key", type: "Control", column: "Control Classification" }, { name: "Compensating", type: "Control", column: "Control Classification" }],
    selection8 = [{ name: "Low", type: "Risk", column: "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating" }, { name: "Lindgren", type: "Risk", column: "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating" }, { name: "High", type: "Risk", column: "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating" }, { name: "Very High", type: "Risk", column: "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating" }, { name: "Partially Effective", type: "Control", column: "Control Effectiveness Rating" }, { name: "Effective", type: "Control", column: "Control Effectiveness Rating" }, { name: "Not Determined", type: "Control", column: "Control Effectiveness Rating" }, { name: "Not Assessed", type: "Risk", column: "Overall Control Effectiveness Rating and Residual Risk Rating" }],
    types = ['bp', 'Risk', 'Control'],
    groupBy = (array, [...types]) => {
        const groups = array.reduce((r, { type, column, name }) => {
            r[type] ??= { type, values: [] };
            const value = r[type].values.find(o => o.column === column);
            if (value) value.name = [].concat(value.name, name);
            else r[type].values.push({ column, name });
            return r;
        }, {});
        while (!(types[types.length - 1] in groups)) types.pop();
        return types.map(type => groups[type] || { type, all: true });
    },
    filter = (array, [{ values, all } = {}, ...selection]) => array.reduce((r, { ...o }) => {
        const type = selection[0]?.type;
        if (all || values.every(({ column, name }) => o[column] === name || Array.isArray(name) && name.includes(o[column]))) {
            if (type in o) {
                const temp = filter(o[type], selection);
                if (temp.length) r.push({ ...o, [type]: temp, });
            } else if (!all) r.push(o);
        }
        return r;
    }, []),
    getResult = (data, selection) => {
        const groups = groupBy(selection, types);
        console.log('>>>>>>>>>>');
        console.log(groups);
        return filter(data, groups);
    };

console.log(getResult(data, selection1));
console.log(getResult(data, selection2));
console.log(getResult(data, selection3));
console.log(getResult(data, selection4));
console.log(getResult(data, selection5));
console.log(getResult(data, selection6));
console.log(getResult(data, selection7));
console.log(getResult(data, selection8));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```